# Adding a transition effect to a winform?

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I want to know if there is a way that I can add transition effects to my winforms.

I have about 3 winforms on my application (vb.net) that open at the top of the screen. My client is concerned with aesthetics, so transitions is one requirements for the forms to show up when called.

Maybe transition is not accurate. What I mean is having the form move from left to right when called. or top to bottom.

Are there any resources, to help accomplish this?

Comment: Tell them to upgrade to Windows Vista or later and enable the Aero theme. Boom, instant transition effects whenever forms are opened and closed!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest way is to use a Timer and increase Opacity in a few steps over a second or two.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.windows.forms.form.opacity.aspx

An example:

Form1:

```
Public Class Form1

    Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
        Dim f As Form2
        f = New Form2
        f.Timer1.Enabled = True
        f.Timer1.Interval = 5
        f.Opacity = 0
        f.ShowDialog(Me)
    End Sub

End Class
```

Form2:

```
Public Class Form2
    Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
        If Me.Opacity >= 1 Then
            Timer1.Stop()
            Exit Sub
        End If
        Me.Opacity += 0.05
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Why have Form1 set Form2's Timer and it's Opacity, keep that information in Form2 and start the Timer in Form2's OnShown EventHandler.

Comment: Just wanted to take things off the designer and into code quickly so it can be tested faster... not a real life example.

Comment: With your example Form1 is not hidden, transition is OK, but Form1 is still shown in the back?

Comment: @Jovica in this (quick and dirty) example yes. You could add `Me.Owner.Opacity -= 0.05` after the other opacity-line to fade out Form1. (But that would probably lead to more necessary changes in managing the forms)